# Using Dictionary with nested Generics from Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics

i'm trying to create following structure. Intellisense & Compiler are giving me 
`Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Test.IFactory<T>' to 'Test.IFactory<Test.AbstractClass>'`. I am quite sure that the object I try to add to the dictionary has the correct type. Am i missing something?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
}

public interface IFactory<T> where T : AbstractClass
{
    T Create();
}

public class Manager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IFactory<AbstractClass>> _factories = new Dictionary<Type, IFactory<AbstractClass>>();

    void RegisterFactory<T>(IFactory<T> factory) where T : AbstractClass
    {
        _factories.Add(typeof(T), factory); // <-- Error in here
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have a dictionary of fruit baskets. You are thinking "T is a fruit, so a T basket is a fruit basket, right"?  Wrong.  T could be apple, but the dictionary requires a basket into which you can put any fruit. A basket of apples can only accept apples, not any fruit.

Comment: Factory needs to be explicitly of the type IFactory<AbstractClass>, that's how it is defined.